# soapclient request https server error, 'You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port'

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

```
Operating-system:centos6.
Php-version:5.3.
File-fromat:WSDL.
Finally i get this error.
>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Here are the package i catched.
```

> POST /index.php/soap/wsdl HTTP/1.1
>      Host: 127.0.0.1:443
>      Connection: Keep-Alive
>      User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3
>      Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="urn:serviceName#test_server#test"
>      Content-Length: 338
>
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>      Date: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 07:47:59 GMT
>      Server: Apache
>      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>      Vary: Accept-Encoding
>      Content-Length: 362
>      Connection: close
>      Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>      Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>      Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
>
> > > Here are my code.

```
    $url = "https://127.0.0.1/soap/wsdl?wsdl";
    $context = stream_context_create(array( 
        'ssl' => array(
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            // 'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'SNI_enabled' => false
        ),
        'https' => array(
            'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false,
            'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => false
        )
    ));
    $client = new SoapClient($url,array('stream_context' => $context,'trace' => 1,'exceptions' => true, 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2));

    try{
        $response = $client->__soapCall("test",array());
        echo $response;
    }catch (SoapFault $f){
        var_dump($f->getMessage());
        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
        var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
    }
```

Comment: The error seems fairly clear. You need to send your request using `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: What would be your question? Describe the situation you are solving and the area you need help with. Better questions get better answers.

Comment: @ADyson  I'm sorry didn't post my code before.But the url requested is 'HTTPS'.

Comment: Ok, but does the endpoint actually have an SSL certificate associated with it? From your update, I can see the URL is `127.0.0.1`, which is the local machine. Usually, SSL certificates are not enabled for local requests. You would have to take extra steps to install, and then get your code to trust, a local, self-signed certificate. Maybe you should just use HTTP for local testing.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, it worked normal when use the protocl of http.But our environment require "https",so i'm try to resolve this problem.Finally i come here to ask for help

Comment: "But our environment require "https""... personally I would use a development server to test it, where you can install a proper SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The param $location in the function of __doRequest change to "http://***.***.***.***:443/"

Rewrite code.

```
public function __construct ($wsdl, $options=null) 
{
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}

public function __doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
{
    $url_parts = parse_url ($location);
    if($url_parts["scheme"]=="http"&&$url_parts['port']=="443")
    {
        $location = substr_replace($location,"https",0,4);
    }
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
```